# Split the String based on start and end points

Tags: java

how to split the string

'ABCDEFGHIJK'

I know starting point and ending point for a string

```
Startid endid
1       2
3       5
6       7
8       11

AS
-----

AB
CDE
FG
HIJK
```

Comment: Can you show us any code? We can help you based on that.

Comment: You don't need much efforts for this, String class provides you method to do that. Go through it.

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = string.subString(startpoint,endpoint);
```

Comment: Almost, lets not forget that characters are indexed from 0 and OP wants 1 to be first character.

Comment: The Java String class does't have a subString method, it has a substring method, note the lowercase. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7034264/5626568

Answer (score 1):

> stringVar.subString(sPoint,ePoint);

make sure you reset the values of sPoint and ePoint periodically

Answer (score 0):

```
final String toSplit = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

for(final Split split : splits){
    if(null != split){
        if(0 <= split.startid  && split.startid < toSplit.length() && 0 <= split.endid && split.endid < toSplit.length()){
            return toSplit.substring(startid, endid);
        }
    }

    return StringUtils.EMPTY;
}
```

Assuming a class Split containing your startid/endid (other option possible of course):

```
class Split {
    public int startid;
    public int endid;

    public Split(int startid, int endid){
        this.startid = startid;
        this.endid = endid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table you want

```
String s = string.subString(startpoint-1,endpoint-1);
```

And if you like you could misuse the class [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) (would be better to just create your own object) do the following

```
String s = "ABCEDEFG..." // you string
// Create a list of your points (start and end)
List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
// Add your points
list.add(new Point(1,2));
list.add(new Point(3,5)); //etc
// Then do this to get your substring
String[] splits = new String[list.size()]
int i= 0;
for(Point p: list)
{
   splits[i] = s.substring(p.getX()-1, p.getY()-1)
   i++;
}
```

Comment: **ERROR** import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class split
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
  String s = "ABCEDEFG" ;
  List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
  list.add(new Point(1,2));
  list.add(new Point(3,5)); 
  String[] splits = new String[list.size()];
  int i= 0;
   for(Point p: list)
   {
      splits[i] = s.substring(p.getX()-1, p.getY()-1);
         System.out.println(splits[i]);
      i++;
   }
 }
}
symbol  :method substring(double,double)
location:class java.lang.String
splits[i] =s.substring(p.getX()-1,p.getY()-1);

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getSubString(String myString,int statIndex,int endIndex){
       return myString.substring(statIndex,endIndex);
}
```

Comment: Why create another method that will be used like `getSubString(myString,statIndex,endIndex)` if we already have `myString.substring(statIndex,endIndex);`? Just asking...